# How to delete text inserted after a bookmark so i can insert new text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have set up a few bookmarks and when a button is pressed runs a macro to insert dates at the bookmarks, This works great. if i press the button again new dates are inserted before the existing dates.

I want to know what code to use to remove the old dates and add new dates.

I did find some code that lists all my bookmarks.

```
Dim d As Document
'Set d = Documents.Add("G:\My Drive\Moss\CRM\Work in progress\action plan 
\Wordchange.docm")
Set d = ActiveDocument

Dim b As Bookmark

Dim dt As Date
'dt = DateAdd("d", 21, DateTime.Now)
dt = DateAdd("d", 90, Date)
Set b = d.Bookmarks("weeksadd3m")
b.Range.Text = Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

I would like to clear text after bookmark so fresh dates can be inserted.

Thanks to all that will consider this.

moss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bookmark must be set to cover the range of its new content. Try code like this:-

```
Private Sub SetBookMark()

    Dim Doc As Document
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Mark As String
    Dim Dt As Date

    'Set Doc = Documents.Add("G:\My Drive\Moss\CRM\Work in progress\" & _
                             "action plan\Wordchange.docm")
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Mark = "weeksadd3m"
    Dt = DateAdd("m", 3, Date)

    With Doc.Bookmarks
        If .Exists(Mark) Then
            Set Rng = .Item(Mark).Range
            Rng.Text = Format(Dt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            .Add Mark, Rng
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. I have used a mixture of my old code and yours. just wondered what if that bookmark had not existed. Anyway your answer has helped me solve my problem

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as Selected as a beacon to others. Thank you.